# When people could use taylor's theorem to evaluate the integral and when cannot?

Tags: calculus, integration

When people could use taylor's theorem to evaluate the integral and when cannot? Give one or two counter example please.

There must be something that the taylor's theorem is incapable with otherwise people would had say that this is the golden rule for integration. :)

Comment: It works only for differentiable functions. To be more explicit, the function $f$ needs to be $k$-times differentiable (for a $k$-th order expansion) at a point requires differentiability up to order $k−1$ in a neighborhood of said point.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar - Is it the only restriction?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: I don't see how $k$ is related to the integral. I think you did not answer the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only for differentiable functions. To be more explicit, the function $f$ needs to be $k$-times differentiable (for a $k$-th order expansion) at a point requires differentiability up to order $k−1$ in a neighborhood of said point. See the discussion at http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=238794.

$$\int f(x)dx=\\
\sum^\infty_{k=0}\int \dfrac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^kdx\text{, only for $k$-times differentiable functions about $x=a$.}$$
For a Taylor series with $k$ terms, $f\in C^k$ - thus, for a Taylor series with $\infty$ terms, $f\in C^\infty$.

For an example where the integral cannot be evaluated, consider about $x=0$ the function $e^{1/x}$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question!

Comment: @Lipschitz It does. To quote the OP, "use taylor's theorem to evaluate the integral and when cannot". I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Lipschitz See my edited answer.

Comment: still wrong, you need to specify what k is supposed to mean in this concept. you say: the function must be k-times differentiable, well: who decides what k is?

Comment: @Lipschitz The person who wants the $k$th order Taylor expansion decides what $k$ is (I'm not talking about just the OP - I'm talking about anyone doing Taylor expansions).

Comment: You need the full series, not only some k th order...

Comment: @Lipschitz Then you need $f$ to be infinitely differentiable.

Comment: It is still wrong, you need that (!)the remainder goes to zero(!) and $f \in C^{\infty}$ , but I think now we both agree that there is no point in this k you mentioned.

Comment: @Lipschitz Yes, that the remainder goes to zero is missing. However, I did state that $f$ needs to be infinitely differentiable, so $f\in C^\infty$.

Comment: $f \in C^{\infty}$ appears nowhere in your answer!

Comment: @Lipschitz See my edited answer.

Comment: okay, let's continue finding errors(besides the fact that you still did not mention that the remainder needs to go to zero). why do integral and series commutate?